# serviço nao inicia apos limpar a memoria

Tags: android, android-service

Olá galera estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que necessita que de um serviço para avisar o usuario de acordo com acontecimentos em intervalos grandes as vezes + de 24h...

entao esta tudo funcionando, eu abro o aplicativo, o serviço inicia, fecho o aplicativo o serviço continua rodando, trás as notificacoes quando necessario...
meus 2 problemas sao o seguintes, meu celular como muitos, tem a função para "limpar a memoria"
quando executo esta funcao, o meu serviço é eliminado e nunca mais volta a rodar, somente se eu abrir o app novamente.
percebi qe outros app como facebook, whatsapp, messenger continuam rodando normalmente apos este processo

o outro é a pos reiniciar o celular o serviço nao roda no boot
informação importante: testei no emulador do android studio, e o start como configurei, funciona... mas no celular meu, por exemplo não... e nao da erro algum.
configurei da seguinte forma:
no manifest:

```
  <receiver android:name=".StartUpBootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

`public class StartUpBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificacaoController valor = new NotificacaoController(context);
    Toast.makeText(context,"ENTROU no STARTBOOTSERVICE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction()) && valor.returnNotificacao().equals("true")) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"STARTBOOTSERVICE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------STARTBOOT");
        context.startService(new Intent(context, ShowNotificationService.class));
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Esses serviços que rodam após a limpeza da memória, muito provavelmente estão consutando a internet.  E, com relação ao segundo ponto, nos novos dispositivos você tem de habilitar espeficamente cada um deles nas configurações permitindo que o sistema operacional os chame após o boot. Verifique se não é isso.

Comment: nas configuracoes seria o manifest? coloquei como a mostrei a cima <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> existe algum outro lugar? desconheço se poder me explicar, agradeço

Comment: Chegou a adicionar a permissão pra esse broadcast? Na internet tem pessoas que sugerem usar o `android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON` também, mas não achei documentação pra esse cara.

Comment: Sobre o `Service`, minha sugestão é verificar se o `onDestroy` é chamado quando executa a limpeza. Caso isso aconteça, inicie seu `Service` novamente no `onDestroy`.

Comment: permissao estou usando o  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

alterei o BOOT_COMPLETED" para QUICKBOOT_POWERON 
desta forma nem nos emuladores ele inicia apos a a reinicializacao do aparelho

sobre o ondestroy, tentei chamar das seguintes formas:
startService(new Intent(this, ShowNotificationService.class));
e tambem tente chamar direto o onCreate(); mas o service nao voltou apos a limpeza de memoria.

Comment: No caso da permissão tem que manter, mas o action eu sugeriria adicionar o `QUICKBOOT_POWERON` junto do `BOOT_COMPLETED` e não remover o outro :D Já no caso do Service, eu recomendaria a abordagem que esse resposta sugere: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7877466/3404639.

Comment: Olá, verifiquei que o codigo funciona em android 5.0 testei em varios samsung que tenho disponibilidade e funciona.
ja o meu celular é um BLU VIVO IV com and 4.4.3 e nele nao inicia de forma alguma, engraçado qe outros app iniciam normalmente, snap, facebook, whats =/

@Wakim sobre o post sugerido é o memso problema que o meu, mas a resposta nao resolveu
percebi que dentro do meu servico, eu dou start em uma peddingIntent em um alarme de 30min em 30min, quando eu baixo esse tempo para 10seg o processo fica praticamente impossivel de finalizar, ele reinicia, e volta com o memso tempo